# Angularjs 1.2rc2: isolated scope differences across browsers (especially older chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, angularjs

I stumbled across a weird issue when testing an application on an old chrome version (5.0.3).

So basically I'm using a controller on a directive like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" class="my-directive-with-isolated-scope">
<!-- ... -->
</div>
```

This seems to be perfectly valid in most recent browsers, however it throws an exception in older versions of Chrome:

```
Multiple directives [myDirectiveWithIsolatedScope, ngController] asking for isolated scope   on:…
```

Any idea why there's a difference?

[Edit]: Just noticed that this also applies to Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably say that having a controller directive and another directive sharing an element may be problematic. In this case, you are saying I want each directive to have an isolated scope on the same element. What is your directives purpose? If you moved your directive to a sub element then the problem would go away. Of course this may not answering your question.

Comment: or you might be able to set priority that is higher/lower than ng-controller should have the same effect

Comment: Thanks, haven't thought of it. Still wondering why there's such a difference across chrome versions (probably v8?).